# Windows Server with 2 NIC's (two subnets) only one subnet controlled by Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, subnet, nic

I have to build up a second network with Windows Server 2012 as DHCP and AD.

The PC for the Windows Server 2012 has two NIC's:

The first one 192.168.10.* (NIC1) should get the IP-Addresses from our Windows-Server and lives in it's own subnet. Except for the Internet-com, that should be handled over the NIC2.

The second one 192.168.20.* (NIC2) gets its IP-addresses from a Linux DHCP but has the connection to the internet.

Is that possible and would there be an easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make sure that NIC1 doesn't get a default gateway by DHCP.

On the DHCP server, use a reservation and in its options set option `003 Router` to nothing. The PC will then use only the default gateway from NIC2.